# How to set the scroll behaviour with react-router's `ScrollRestoration`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using [`ScrollRestoration`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration) to scroll to the top of the page when I'm switching from one page to another with `<Link />`.
Also, I'm using the following code to make all the scrolls smooth.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

But I don't want the smooth behaviour when the scroll is from `ScrollRestoration`. I want it to be  isntant (the default behaviour).

How can I disable the smooth behaviour when the scroll is done by `ScrollRestoration` ?

Comment: Are you asking for the [`scroll-behavior`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_scroll-behavior.php#midcontentadcontainer)'s values? `auto` is the default.

Comment: @Aleksandar no, I want the scroll performed by `ScrollRestoration` to be instant instead of smooth without having to change the css.

Comment: AFAIK the [`ScrollResoration`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L743-L762) component offers no scrolling customizations. For this you may need to look at locally conditionally overriding that global default. Or leave the scroll behavior as "auto" so the browser handles it naturally.

Comment: Hi OP, did you find the solution? I'm experiencing the same. @tguichaoua

Comment: @muchisx No, I didn't